# Short Eratosthenes Sieve

Tags: python, python-3.x, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I've written a short implementation of the Eratosthenes' sieve.

```
def sieve(n):
    l = list(range(2, n + 1))
    out = []
    while len(l) > 0:
        out.append(l[0])
        l = list(filter(lambda n: n % l[0], l))
    return out
```

Is it lacking in efficiency? Are there any improvements or changes you would make?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the implementation is *short*.  However, its *efficiency* is suspect.  That's due to:

1. Reassembling `list` every iteration
2. Testing every remaining member of list using `%` operator

The beauty of Eratosthenes' sieve is that it shouldn't need any division (including `%`).  With an array of values, we simply march along it in steps of `n` striking out members - that requires only addition, which is one of the cheapest operations in a digital computer.  (There's an optimisation that also requires multiplying a number by itself; that's only used because it's *faster* than the equivalent additions).

Removing the empty cells at every iteration prevents us from accessing every nth element in this way, as well as imposing its own overheads (for a start, we'll need lots of extra memory when building the new list from the old).

Comment: Gave +1 mainly for quote: `The beauty of Eratosthenes' sieve is that it shouldn't need any division`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all first statement may be simplified to

```
 l = range(2, n + 1)
```

since `range` objects support indexing, so creating `list` from it will cause performance issues with no gain.
Also it is less noisy to test `list`s for emptyness with

```
while l:
    ...
```

---

Wherever you are dealing with `list`s it may become faster (or at least, less memory consuming) by making calculations "lazy" using iterables/iterators/generators. So your function may be rewritten like

```
def sieve_2(n):
    numbers = iter(range(2, n + 1))

    def to_is_dividable_by(divisor):
        return lambda dividend: dividend % divisor

    while True:
        try:
            prime = next(numbers)
        except StopIteration:
            return
        yield prime
        numbers = filter(to_is_dividable_by(prime), numbers)
```

Note that we are creating predicate on each step since `filter` creates iterator object and if we will use some sort of partial application of prime as divisor to predicate like before:

```
l = filter(lambda n: n % prime, l)
```

this will lead to undesired behavior since `prime` will be modified on each step and all of applied `lambda` functions will change accordingly and have the same `prime` argument due to late binding (more info can be found [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures)).

## Test

On my laptop with Windows 10 in Python 3.6.5 gives

```
>>> from timeit import repeat
>>> min(repeat('sieve(10000)', 'from __main__ import sieve', number=10, repeat=7))
1.198557400000027
>>> min(repeat('list(sieve_2(10000))', 'from __main__ import sieve_2', number=10, repeat=7))
0.9349597000000358
```

Better, but still not so great, so we probably should review our algorithm for further improvements.

Searching on StackOverflow will lead us to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n/46635266#46635266) using which we have

```
>>> min(repeat('rwh_primes1v1(10000)', 'from __main__ import rwh_primes1v1', number=10, repeat=7))
0.003475800000160234
>>> min(repeat('rwh_primes1v2(10000)', 'from __main__ import rwh_primes1v2', number=10, repeat=7))
0.0025113000001510954
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have a `while` loop, which is slower than a `for` loop, and you have to check the length of `l` on every iteration - this wastes time. But that's nothing compared to this line here: `l = list(filter(lambda n: n % l[0], l))` where you're creating a new list, a new function and then applying it to filter the list on each iteration. It's definitely lacking efficiency.

This should be faster:

```
def find_primes(to_n):
    primes = []
    sieve = [0 for n in range(to_n)]
    for n in range(2, to_n):
        if sieve[n] == 0:
            primes.append(n)
            for n_multiple in range(n, to_n, n):
                sieve[n_multiple] = 1
    return primes
```

Why? Because it's pretty much the exact implementation of Sieve of Eratosthenes; it iteratively marks the multiples of prime (second `for` loop) numbers as composites (by giving them a value of 1 in list `sieve`). Your version just adds some unnecessary steps at the cost of making it slightly shorter.